# How to see/track the exact HTTP response (code and message) that an Eventgrid webhook endpoint receives?

Tags: azure-eventgrid

I have a Webhook Eventgrid subscription. I do not have access to the webhook logs or implementation.

Apparently ,Eventgrid receives HTTP code other than success from the webhook, but I do not have any detail visibility to that.

How can I see the exact HTTP interaction (Response message, HTTP Code) for the EventGrid WebHook Bad Requests like the ones pointed below?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the dead letter on your event grid subscription as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/delivery-and-retry#dead-letter-events).
Once the events are not delivered and dead letter now you can review the **lastDeliveryOutcome** property on the dead letter events to know what was the reason the event was not delivered to the configured endpoint.

You cannot find the reason for each request at your end as the event may be delivered at a later point in time once it is retried.

Comment: I was looking for having HTTP visibility to success event web hooks. For failures, I use a log analytics workspace. Wouldn't that work as well?

Comment: Diagnostic logs are for custom topics, system topics, and domains as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/enable-diagnostic-logs-topic) and dead letter for event grid subscription. Web hooks are configured at the event grid subscription end so you need to configure the dead letter to know the reason of failure.

Comment: Then, perhaps the answer is that there is no such feature.